# Loading sandbox AppDomain crashes debugger

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, appdomain

I am creating a sandbox `AppDomain` so I can load up an assembly and release it.

```
var sandbox = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Sandbox", null, 
   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation);
```

However when I `Load` an assembly into to `sandbox`, the debugger crashes. I am in ASP.NET.

```
var assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(assemblyPath);
var assembly = pluginDomain.Load(assemblyName); // crash here
```

Anyone know why this crashes?

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate on what you mean by "Debugger Crashes".  Does Visual Studio itself crash, does the debugger just stop and returns to Visual Studio design mode, does an exception dialog popup, etc ...

For all of these cases though the first thing I would do would be to change the following debugger options and repeat the scenario.

```
- Tools -> Options -> Debugger
- Uncheck: Enable implicit property evaluation
- Uncheck: Enable Just My Code
```

Comment: The VS just returns to design mode, no exceptions.

Comment: @Daniel, in my experience that's an indication that the debugger initiated a func eval on the target process which resulted in a stack overflow exception.  This is main cause of repeatable and sudden exits of the debugger.  Does it repro if you disable implicit func eval?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue: Only when debugging, my program quit without any exception when accessing AppDomain. After looking in the event viewer, I saw that Microsoft.IntelliTrace.Profiler caused application errors.

The solution was disabling intellitrace:

Uncheck: Tools -> Options -> intelliTrace -> Enable intelliTrace